# Why does not `\spaceskip` work inside a TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

In my document, I need to increase `\spaceskip` in order to inject more space between words to make them more readable. However, the setting does not seem to apply to text that's inside a TikZ node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\spaceskip 2ex

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  a b c\\
  \tikz{%
    \node [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] {%
      a b c%
    };
  }%
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get my customized word-spacing to work even inside TikZ nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the beginning of each `tikzpicture`, `TikZ` selects `nullfont` and sets `\spaceskip` to zero. Then, in each node content, `TikZ` resets `\spaceskip` to `.3333em`.

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\spaceskip 2ex
\tikzset{every node/.style={execute at begin node={\spaceskip 2ex}}}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  a b c\\
  \tikz{%
    \node [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] {%
      a b c%
    };
  }%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ingenious! Can't believe it was that simple. =)

Comment: Mmm… still it would be nice to know why is that necessary.

Comment: @Manuel I edited my answer.